# md-dialog Angular material/material2 abnormal behaviour (it hides the fixed position div)

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular2-template, angular-material2

Actually i'm working on Angular 4 with material2 design , so i came across `<md-dialog>` , decided to use in my app.

App contain a header i.e *fixed* `position:fixed` and a sidebar *fixed* as well.

i used `<md-dialog>` and yup it works fine until page is **not scrolled** , but when page scrolls somewhere at bottom of page, on click of button that trigger `<md-dialog>` a unusual behaviour arises that the **fixed position** *div* hides behind the `<md-dialog>`

working plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/1F5La3HPmd8RxXtPip3o?p=preview

Any help to remove that behaviour ?

Comment: The problem is that you're using Angular 2+ material with AngularJS, not Angular 2+. AngularJS is 1.x, and doesn't support Angular 2+ - Material.

Comment: Its tested in angular4 with material2 as well , but facing same issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you were having was that you were creating a fixed position div without a location. You need to set at least one of the "top" "left" "right" "bottom" styles when using fixed. See [this working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/QAHQeB5SC4bAMYYyGAf6?p=preview).

Most notable html:

```
<div id="toolc" style="position:fixed; border:4px solid red;color:white;background-color:black;top:15px;left:15px">Fixed Div</div>
<div style="height:100px"></div>
<button md-button (click)="openDialog()">Launch dialog</button>
You chose: {{selectedOption}}
<div style="height:300px;"></div>
<div>scroll down</div>
<div style="height:600px;"></div>
<p>scroll down</p>
<button md-button (click)="openDialog()">Launch dialog</button>
```

This problem occurs because MdDialog changes the `<html>` tag 'top' style to ensure the dialog is always on the screen on click. It will shift fixed divs if they do not have a 'top' style as well.

Comment: Great ! did'nt know that  MdDialog changes the `<html>` tag `top-style`

Comment: Amazing! thanks a lot. I added top: 0 to my sidebar and everything works as expected